# Combine Record by Id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am Using SQLServer2008.

Output of My Stored Procedure is :

```
--------------------------------------------------------
 BrokerCode | MemberId  |  FY    |    SY    |    TY    |
--------------------------------------------------------
    104     |    24     |  1140  |    0.00  |    0.00  |
--------------------------------------------------------
    104     |    24     |  1140  |    570   |    0.00  |
--------------------------------------------------------
    104     |    30     |  500   |    0.00  |    0.00  |
--------------------------------------------------------
    104     |    30     |  500   |    360   |    0.00  |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

And I want to result like :

```
--------------------------------------------------------
 BrokerCode | MemberId  |   FY    |    SY    |    TY    |
--------------------------------------------------------
    104     |    24     |   1140  |    570   |    0.00  |
--------------------------------------------------------
    104     |    30     |   500   |    360   |    0.00  |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

So i have tried using :

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
SELECT BrockerCode,
     MemberId,

     RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId ORDER BY MemberID),
     FY=MIN(FY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId),
     SY=MIN(SY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId),
     TY=MIN(TY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId)

     FROM   @tablePromotee )
SELECT MemberId,BrockerCode,FY,SY,TY  FROM  CTE  WHERE  RN = 1
```

but still it display wrong result...please help me..where i am wrong? Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't it be `FY=MAX(FY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId)` instead of `MIN` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use "GROUP BY " in your query 
Like,

```
SELECT BrockerCode,
     MemberId,
     MIN(FY)
     MIN(SY)
     MIN(TY)
     FROM   @tablePromotee GROUP BY BrockerCode, MemberId
```

There are multiple aggregate function on sql server you can use from them as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`Common Table Expression` isn't really required here. A much simpler query:

```
SELECT 
      BrokerCode,
      MemberId,
      MAX(FY) AS FY,
      MAX(SY) AS SY,
      MAX(TY) AS TY
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY BrokerCode, MemberId
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68619/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      MemberId
    , BrockerCode
    , FY = MAX(FY)
    , SY = MAX(SY)
    , TY = MAX(TY)  
FROM (
    SELECT 
          BrockerCode
        , MemberId
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId ORDER BY MemberID)
        , FY = MIN(FY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId)
        , SY = MIN(SY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId)
        , TY = MIN(TY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId)
    FROM @tablePromotee 
)  
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY 
      BrokerCode
    , MemberId
```

Or try this -

```
SELECT TOP 1
      BrockerCode
    , MemberId
    , FY = MAX(MIN(FY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId))
    , SY = MAX(MIN(SY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId))
    , TY = MAX(MIN(TY)OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId))
FROM @tablePromotee 
GROUP BY 
      BrokerCode
    , MemberId
ORDER BY MemberId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   SELECT BrockerCode,
          MemberId, FY,SUM(SY),SUM(TY) FROM @tablePromotee Group By BrockerCode,
          MemberId, FY
```

Comment: then go with other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using group by wont work as you may end up in getting o.oo values
change last line of your existing code as below, hope you want this.

```
 SELECT MemberId,BrockerCode,FY,SY,TY  FROM  CTE  WHERE  RN = 1 and SY<>0
 ROUP BY BrockerCode, MemberId
```